# AWS Glue does not give coherent result for pyspark - orderBy

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

when running pyspark locally I get correct results with list ordered by BOOK_ID, But when deploying the AWS Glue job, the books seem not to be ordered

```
root
 |-- AUTHORID: integer
 |-- NAME: string 
 |-- BOOK_LIST: array 
 |    |-- BOOK_ID: integer 
 |    |-- BOOK_NAME: string
```

```
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    
    result = (df_authors.join(df_books, on=["AUTHOR_ID"], how="left")
              .orderBy(F.col("BOOK_ID").desc())
              .groupBy("AUTHOR_ID", "NAME")
              .agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("BOOK_ID", "BOOK_NAME")))
              )
```

Note: I'm using `pyspark 3.2.1` and `Glue 2.0`

Any suggestion please

Comment: Two things to check:
1. Order by at the end, probably the aggregation change the order.
2. check the glue schema types, maybe somehow its strings ?

Anyway I think its option 1 - but let me know

Comment: @BennyElgazar for the first option, I don't think that we can do the `orderBy` at the end of the agg, In fact we need to order the collected_list

Comment: @BennyElgazar for the 2nd supposition, the output json file display the values (BOOKID) as `integers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Supposition

Although I managed to run the job on Glue 3.0 that supports `spark 3.1`, the **orderBy** still giving wrong result

[Migrating from AWS Glue 2.0 to AWS Glue 3.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/migrating-version-30.html#migrating-version-30-from-20)

The solution that seems to give a good result is to reduce the number of workers to **2** which is the minimum allowed number of workers
[image]

> The explanation is: Glue jobs may have many workers that allow parallelism, thus the orderBy can't give a correct result in contrary where we have only one worker

## Suggested Sollution

- Use the minimum number of workers (which is not a pertinent solution)
- Apply the **.orderBy** for each dataframe before the `join`
- Or use `.coalesce(1)`

```
 result = (df_authors.join(df_books, on=["AUTHOR_ID"], how="left")
              .coalesce(1)
              .orderBy(F.col("BOOK_ID").desc())
              .groupBy("AUTHOR_ID", "NAME")
              .agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("BOOK_ID", "BOOK_NAME")))
              )
```

Which allow to get the right result but in this case we lose in performance

Comment: That looks very strange and a git issue material

Answer (score -2):

Im trying to simplify the issue, work with me:

Lets create a dataframe sample:

```py
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([
    {"book_id": 1, "author_id": 1, "name": "David", "book_name": "Kill Bill"},
    {"book_id": 2, "author_id": 2, "name": "Roman", "book_name": "Dying is Hard"},
    {"book_id": 3, "author_id": 3, "name": "Moshe", "book_name": "Apache Kafka The Easy Way"},
    {"book_id": 4, "author_id": 1, "name": "David", "book_name": "Pyspark Is Awesome"},
    {"book_id": 5, "author_id": 2, "name": "Roman", "book_name": "Playing a Piano"},
    {"book_id": 6, "author_id": 3, "name": "Moshe", "book_name": "Awesome Scala"}
 ])
```

Now, Doing this:

```
(
df
.groupBy("author_id", "name")
.agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("book_id", "book_name")).alias("data"), F.sum("book_id").alias("sorted_key"))
.orderBy(F.col("sorted_key").desc()).drop("sorted_key")
.show(10, False)
)
```

Im getting exactly what you are allegedly asking for:

```
+---------+-----+----------------------------------------------------+
|author_id|name |collect_list(struct(book_id, book_name))            |
+---------+-----+----------------------------------------------------+
|3        |Moshe|[{3, Apache Kafka The Easy Way}, {6, Awesome Scala}]|
|2        |Roman|[{2, Dying is Hard}, {5, Playing a Piano}]          |
|1        |David|[{1, Kill Bill}, {4, Pyspark Is Awesome}]           |
+---------+-----+----------------------------------------------------+
```